Camera is not active
Failed to submit capture request
androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Failed to submit capture request
    at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.TakePictureManager$1.onFailure(TakePictureManager.java:268)
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:345)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)
Caused by: androidx.camera.core.CameraControl$OperationCanceledException: Camera is not active.
    at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraControlImpl.submitStillCaptureRequests(Camera2CameraControlImpl.java:476)
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.submitStillCaptureRequest(ImageCapture.java:1127)
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$1.submitStillCaptureRequests(ImageCapture.java:972)
    at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.TakePictureManager.submitCameraRequest(TakePictureManager.java:249)
    at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.TakePictureManager.issueNextRequest(TakePictureManager.java:214)
    at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.TakePictureManager.offerRequest(TakePictureManager.java:117)
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.takePictureInternal(ImageCapture.java:1044)
    at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.takePicture(ImageCapture.java:746)
    at com.example.smartlagoon.ui.screens.camera.CameraScreenKt.takePhoto(CameraScreen.kt:249)
    at com.example.smartlagoon.ui.screens.camera.CameraScreenKt.access$takePhoto(CameraScreen.kt:1)
    at com.example.smartlagoon.ui.screens.camera.CameraScreenKt$CameraScreen$1$3$1.invokeSuspend(CameraScreen.kt:155)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878) 

@Composable
fun CameraScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    photosDbVm: PhotosDbViewModel,
    challengesDbVm: ChallengesDbViewModel,
    usersDbVm: UsersDbViewModel,
) {
    val ctx = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val cameraProviderFuture = remember { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ctx) }
    val previewView = remember { PreviewView(ctx) }
    val imageCapture = remember { mutableStateOf<ImageCapture?>(null) }
    val cameraSelector = remember { mutableStateOf(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA) }
    val cameraControl = remember { mutableStateOf<CameraControl?>(null) }
    val isFlashEnabled = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isPressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val currentChallenge by challengesDbVm.currentChallenge.observeAsState()

    Log.d("currentChallengeCamera", currentChallenge.toString())
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // Anteprima della fotocamera
        AndroidView(
            factory = { previewView },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )

        // Configura CameraX
        LaunchedEffect(cameraProviderFuture) {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
            }

            val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
            imageCapture.value = imageCaptureConfig

            try {
                // Disattiva tutti i use cases
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Associa i use cases alla fotocamera
                val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    lifecycleOwner,
                    cameraSelector.value,
                    preview,
                    imageCaptureConfig
                )

                // Ottieni il controllo della fotocamera per gestire zoom e flash
                cameraControl.value = camera.cameraControl

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e("CameraX", "Impossibile associare i use cases alla fotocamera", exc)
            }
        }

        // Pulsante per scattare la foto
        Button(
            onClick = {
                isPressed = true // Cambia lo stato del bottone

                // Avvia una coroutine per gestire il delay
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    // Utilizza la funzione takePhoto modificata
                    takePhoto(ctx, imageCapture.value) { uri ->
                        if (uri != null) {
                            photosDbVm.uploadPhoto(uri)
                        } else {
                            Log.e(
                                "CameraScreen",
                                "Errore: URI della foto è nullo. Foto non caricata."
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    delay(500L) // Delay di 1 secondo (1000 millisecondi)
                    isPressed = false // Ripristina lo stato del bottone
                }
                Log.d("caricamentoFoto","aaa")
                if(currentChallenge != null) {
                    currentChallenge?.let { usersDbVm.addPoints(it.points) }
                    currentChallenge?.id?.let { challengesDbVm.challengeDone(it) }
                    photosDbVm.setShowDialog(true)
                    navController.navigate(SmartlagoonRoute.Photo.route)
                }else {
                    navController.navigateUp() // Torna indietro dopo il delay
                }
                scheduleNotification(ctx)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                .size(70.dp) // Dimensione per creare una forma tonda
                .clip(CircleShape), // Clip a forma circolare
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                containerColor = if (isPressed) Color.Red else Color.White, // Colore del bottone basato sullo stato
                contentColor = Color.Transparent // Nessun colore del contenuto (per l'icona)
            )
        ) {

        }

        // Pulsante per commutare la fotocamera
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                cameraSelector.value = if (cameraSelector.value == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA) {
                    CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA
                } else {
                    CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.FlipCameraAndroid,
                contentDescription = "Cambia Fotocamera",
                tint = Color.White
            )
        }

        // Pulsante per abilitare/disabilitare il flash
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                isFlashEnabled.value = !isFlashEnabled.value
                cameraControl.value?.enableTorch(isFlashEnabled.value)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .padding(16.dp),

        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = if (isFlashEnabled.value) Icons.Default.FlashOn else Icons.Default.FlashOff,
                contentDescription = "Controllo Flash",
                tint = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}

private fun takePhoto(context: Context, imageCapture: ImageCapture?, onPhotoTaken: (Uri?) -> Unit) {
    if (imageCapture == null) {
        Log.e("CameraX", "Errore: ImageCapture non è pronto.")
        onPhotoTaken(null)
        return
    }else {
        Log.e("CameraX", "NON NULLO")
    }

    // Crea un file temporaneo per salvare la foto
    val photoFile = File(
        context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
        "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
    )

    val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

    imageCapture.takePicture(
        outputOptions,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e("CameraX", "Errore durante lo scatto della foto: ${exception.message}", exception)
                onPhotoTaken(null) // Chiamata di callback con URI nullo in caso di errore
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                Log.d("CameraX", "Foto salvata con successo: ${photoFile.absolutePath}")

                // Verifica se il file esiste prima di procedere
                if (photoFile.exists()) {
                    val uri = photoFile.toUri()
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Foto caricata!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    onPhotoTaken(uri) // Chiamata di callback con URI valido
                } else {
                    Log.e("CameraX", "Il file della foto non esiste!")
                    onPhotoTaken(null) // Chiamata di callback con URI nullo
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

I can se the preview and when I click it become full screen but it'n not working.
imageCapture is not null and there are two cameras available
val availableCameras = cameraProvider.availableCameraInfos

if (availableCameras.isEmpty()) {
    Log.e("CameraX", "Nessuna fotocamera disponibile sul dispositivo.")
    return // O gestisci l'errore in modo appropriato
}

// Log delle informazioni sulle fotocamere disponibili per il debugging
availableCameras.forEach { cameraInfo ->
    Log.d("CameraX", "Camera disponibile: ${cameraInfo.cameraSelector}")
}

